# Angular: Return string from http Request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I've got an API with a model "Movie". The movie is linked to a genre. When I'm getting the movie from the API I get the url to the genre as the "genre" attribute.
In my code I'm creating a movie like this:

```
fetchMovies(token: string){

    this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
    };

    return this.http.get<{[key: string]: MovieData}>(this.url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      map(res => {
        const movies = [];
        for (const key in res) {
          if (res.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            movies.push(
              new Movie(
                key,
                res[key].title,
                res[key].desc,
                res[key].year,
                this.getGenre(res[key], res[key].genre),
                res[key].thumbnail,
                res[key].movie,
                res[key].createdUser,
                res[key].premium));
          }
        }
        return movies;
      }),
      tap(movies => {
        this._movies = movies;
      })
    );
  }
```

The `getGenre()` method sould return the genre as a string.

I tried the following:

```
getGenre(key, url): string{
      let result;
      this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          result = res.title;
        }
      );
      return result;
    }
```

How can I achive this?

I'm open for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on Typescript classes:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html. You will want to create a method that can be called.

I uses classes within my Ionic project all the time so that my API responses are strongly typed.

Here is an example

```
class Movie
{
  ID:number;
  Title:string;
  Genre:string
  constructor(myMovie?:Partial<Movie>)
  {
    Object.assign(this,myMovie);
  }
  getGenre()
  {
    return this.Genre;
  }
}
```

You can strongly type your HTTP response by adding  before each verb (GET,POST) and also casting the response in the then block.

Answer (score 0):

in angular using httpClient, **you have to set responseType as text**

```
getGenre() {
 return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

But still you need to subscribe to it to get the string value

```
firstCall.pipe(
 switchMap((res) => {
  return combineLatest(this.getGenre(res[key], res[key].genre), of(res))
 })
).subscribe(([genre, data]) => {
    new Movie(
     key,
     data[key].title,
     data[key].desc,
     data[key].year,
     genre,
     data[key].thumbnail,
     data[key].movie,
     data[key].createdUser,
     data[key].premium));
})
```

Comment: from where you get "res" is it an http call too?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get that completely. I updated my Question with the whole code. Can you work with that?